# Display randomly selected items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 boxes and an array of items. How do I display 5 items in 5 boxes, randomly selected without repetition?

Is it a problem with:

`ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;`

that it is not displaying in the box?

I tried many ways without success. I use DreamWeaver as IDE, might there be a problem with that?

```js
var array2 = [];
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: '1.png'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: '2.png'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: '3.png'
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    url: '4.png'
  },
  {
    label: '5',
    url: '5.png'
  },
  {
    label: '6',
    url: '6.png'
  },
  {
    label: '7',
    url: '7.png'
  },
  {
    label: '8',
    url: '8.png'
  },
  {
    label: '9',
    url: '9.png'
  },
  {
    label: '10',
    url: '10.png'
  },
  {
    label: '11',
    url: '11.png'
  },
  {
    label: '12',
    url: '12.png'
  }
];

array2 = items.slice();
console.log(array2);
rvalue();

var item;

function rvalue() {
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  console.log(ptags);
  for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
    item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    console.log(item);

    ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
  }

}

console.log(array2);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.box {
  width: calc(15.4% - 4px);
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #0F6;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 7 px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" id="10">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="11">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="12">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="13">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="14">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've a correct code you need just to put the code inside a ready function or just move it to the end of the body after the HTML tags to make sure the DOM was loaded before the script run.

For that there's severals solution I suggest the use of the `DOMContentLoaded` event :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //Your code here 
});
```

**NOTE:** To detect such bugs the next time by your self you could check the length of the result first like :

```
console.log( document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]').length );
```

If the length is zero and you have a correct selector then you need to check the DOM availability.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <style>
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .heading {
      margin-left: 20%;
      margin-right: 20%;
      margin-top: -2%;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: calc(15.4% - 4px);
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
      margin: -2px;
      background-color: #0F6;
    }
    
    .box {
      height: 15vh;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center
    }
    
    #container {
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
      border: px solid #CC0000;
      margin: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
    }
    
    .box p {
      font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
    }
    
    p {
      font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #005ce6;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .text {
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 7 px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    body {
      background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var array2 = [];
      var items = [{
          label: '1',
          url: '1.png'
        },
        {
          label: '2',
          url: '2.png'
        },
        {
          label: '3',
          url: '3.png'
        },
        {
          label: '4',
          url: '4.png'
        },
        {
          label: '5',
          url: '5.png'
        },
        {
          label: '6',
          url: '6.png'
        },
        {
          label: '7',
          url: '7.png'
        },
        {
          label: '8',
          url: '8.png'
        },
        {
          label: '9',
          url: '9.png'
        },
        {
          label: '10',
          url: '10.png'
        },
        {
          label: '11',
          url: '11.png'
        },
        {
          label: '12',
          url: '12.png'
        }
      ];

      array2 = items.slice();
      rvalue();

      var item;

      function rvalue() {
        ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');

        for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
          var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
          item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

          ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;

          ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
        }

      }
    });
  </script>


  <div id="container">

    <div class="box" id="10">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="11">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="12">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="13">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="14">
      <p name="values"></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome, Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error as your script runs before the elements occur. You need to swap the positions of your container and script tag as mentioned below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.heading {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-top: -2%;
}

.box {
  width: calc(15.4% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #0F6;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 7 px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

  <div class="box" id="10">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="11">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="12">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="13">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="14">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
var array2 = [];
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: '1.png'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: '2.png'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: '3.png'
  },
  {
    label: '4',
    url: '4.png'
  },
  {
    label: '5',
    url: '5.png'
  },
  {
    label: '6',
    url: '6.png'
  },
  {
    label: '7',
    url: '7.png'
  },
  {
    label: '8',
    url: '8.png'
  },
  {
    label: '9',
    url: '9.png'
  },
  {
    label: '10',
    url: '10.png'
  },
  {
    label: '11',
    url: '11.png'
  },
  {
    label: '12',
    url: '12.png'
  }
];

array2 = items.slice();
console.log(array2);
rvalue();

var item;

function rvalue() {
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
console.log(ptags);
  for (var index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
    item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    console.log(item);

    ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
  }

}

console.log(array2);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or if you don't want to swap the positions then just wrap your code under the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   // INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Comment: have you tested your code snipet ? it is giving error

Comment: Yes, it's working fine though. Mistakenly, i have pasted the same code as provided in the question instead swapping the positions as mentioned. Please check now.